# Why is it recommended to perform wudu' when one is angry?

Tags: source-identification, islamic-basis, wudu, shaitan, anger

I often hear statements like:

> "Anger is from Satan"

And that one should perform wudu' to calm down from anger. I'd like to learn more about this practice therefore here my questions:

Does this recommendation to perfrom wudu' has any basis in Islam?

If that is true could you elaborate how and why this should work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This concept comes from a weak chained Hadith:

> إِنَّ الْغَضَبَ مِنْ الشَّيْطَانِ وَإِنَّ الشَّيْطَانَ خُلِقَ مِنْ
>   النَّارِ وَإِنَّمَا تُطْفَأُ النَّارُ بِالْمَاءِ فَإِذَا غَضِبَ
>   أَحَدُكُمْ فَلْيَتَوَضَّأْ
>
> Anger is from Shaytan and Shaytan is made from fire. Verily fire is
>   put out with water, so if any of you become angry, then make Wudu'

However, while the chain may be weak, the meaning is acceptable and correct from a medicinal standpoint. That is why scholars have used this Hadith and encouraged people to make Wudu' when angry, because the water provides calmness and weakens the "boiling" anger can bring.

[Source](https://islamqa.info/ar/133861)

Comment: Oh you are still alive!

Answer (score -1):

What I would say is that if anger is beneficial to someone,it becomes a good deed.Same goes with laughter.Ive heard the prophet tell a joke to make an old lady happy.Anger has many possibilities.It can become a good deed,bad deed and can change itself either way.You never know.